# ExtJS4 - How to make an initial entry to a site with param data?

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc, extjs4.2

I have an ExtJS4 site **www.mysite.com** where I serve index.html when a user enter the site.  I want the user to be able to access the site with some param data redirected from another site.  For example, **www.mysite.com?q=10**

1. How do I capture q=10 which I will use to retrieve some data from the database?
2. How do I send index.html so that browser retrieves javascript and css files.  Once all the javascript and css files are loaded, I need to render a page displaying the result from the database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the url parameters I've done this :

```
var getParams = document.URL.split("?");

var params = Ext.urlDecode(getParams[getParams.length - 1]);

console.log(params.q) // you should see 10 being printed
```

If index.html is gonna come with some param in the url you can use the launch method to do an ajax request and bassed on that response render something

```
    Ext.application({
    name : 'MyAppWithDynamicFirstPage',

    launch : function() {

    var getParams = document.URL.split("?");

    var params = Ext.urlDecode(getParams[getParams.length - 1]);

    var q = params.q;

       Ext.Ajax.request({
       url: 'someServlet/getViewToRender',
       params: {

          'q': q       

       },
   success: function(response, opts) {

     //bassed on this you would do something else like render some specific panel on your viewport

   },
   failure: function(response, opts) {
      console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
   }
});





}
});
```

I hope this was of some help.

Best regards.

Comment: Could you please point me to the documentation for `Ext.urlDecode`.  If possible in ExtJs 4.2

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/core/manual/content/utility.html here is something I just found

Comment: Even though I have solved it using javascript outside ExtJs, I prefer this solution.  I will accept this to help others to find it.  The Utility has been moved and renamed in ExtJs 4.2. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.Object

Comment: Right instead of urlDecode, Ext.Object.fromQueryString should be used

Answer (score 0):

1. Depends of your web server, programming language and architecture
2. Usually first ExtJs is loading with all js/css. After it loaded, data loads asynchronously from the server. But if you exactly know what are you doing, you can render your data into a global variable inside a `script` tag and then use it in the code.

Comment: It is Tomcat/Java serving REST request.  When user enters at the root, index.html is served which requests for js/css.  How do I handle a redirected request with some data.  For example, user is redirected to my site http://www.mysite.com?q=10&p=5.  In this case the user has bypassed the root of this site.

Comment: This question is not about ExtJs, but you can read this [getParameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String))